# Using Python, a command with new lines getting truncated

Tags: python-3.x

I have a FIO config which has numerous lines, I am using 'echo' to write the contents of the config to a new file.

```py
config='''[global]
ioengine=libaio   ; async I/O engine for Linux
direct=1
randrepeat=0      ; use same seed for random io for better prediction
thread            ; use thread rather than process
group_reporting
; 
readwrite=randrw
percentage_random=100
iodepth=30
rwmixread=0
blocksize=3434
randrepeat=0
blockalign=3434
runtime=45454
time_based=1

[job 1]
filename=/dev/sdb
filesize=2934m
'''
```

I am trying the following:

```py
cmd = '''echo "%s" > /tmp/fio.cfg''' % config

print(cmd)
```

But I keep getting back:

```sh
echo "[global]"
```

The lines after global are getting truncated. Any ideas are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash and `echo` don't support multi-line strings. When you are formatting your `echo` command, the multiple lines are not going to be represented correctly when you run the command.

```sh
echo "[global]"
```

`echo` is only using the first line of the string that you constructed
with `%s ... % config`, so config must only hold `"[global]"`.

The solution is simple. You don't even have to use bash|shell to do
this work, you can do it all form with-in python.

```py
myconfig='''[global]
ioengine=libaio   ; async I/O engine for Linux
direct=1
randrepeat=0      ; use same seed for random io for better prediction
thread            ; use thread rather than process
group_reporting
; 
readwrite=randrw
percentage_random=100
iodepth=30
rwmixread=0
blocksize=3434
randrepeat=0
blockalign=3434
runtime=45454
time_based=1

[job 1]
filename=/dev/sdb
filesize=2934m"
'''

with open('/tmp/fio.cfg','w') as fo
    fo.write(myconfig)
```

Python does support multi line strings.

Alternatively in bash you could write you strings with `\` chars
where your line breaks are, this will tell bash to treat the next line
as part of the preceding.

```sh
echo "This is a multi line string.\
 It it keeps going on and on."
```

You will get back:

```
This is a multi line string. It it keeps going on and on.
```

Ordinarily in bash scripts returns (new lines) denote the end of a
line of insertion, so that when you progress to the next bash assumes
that you wanted the behaviour that a `;` would give you otherwise.

Adding `\n` new line and adding `-e` to echo will put the output on separate lines.

> [-e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes](https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo)

```sh
echo -e "This is a multi line string\
\nIt it keeps going on and on."
```

You then will get back:

```
This is a multi line string.
It it keeps going on and on.
```

Comment: Thank you @9716278, I ended up using using the simpler option of writing to a file.

Comment: It's not quite true that `bash` doesn't support multiline strings because you can use [heredoc](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) (`<<HEREDOC`) to make them but I agree echoing from one language to another is going to make this hard - why not run `fio` directly from python?

Comment: @Anon oh cool. I didn't know about HEREDOC. https://linuxhint.com/bash-heredoc-tutorial/